# ActionBar logo move left

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, drawerlayout

I want to use logo instead of homeAsUp on actionBar to open drawerLayout, I managed to do it but it seems that the space of homeAsUp is left, so it looks like the logo has leftMargin.

This is what I did:
    **style.xml**

```
<item name="android:logo">@drawable/logo_file</item> 
<item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>
```

**logo_file.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/mylogo"
        android:left="-10dp"
</layer-list>
```

**Activity**

```
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

Doing `android:left="-10dp"` does not solve the problem it only removes 10dp from the left of logo.

So please help me to move the logo left.

Comment: You can use your own custom actionbar in toolbar and set it as actionbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to do the following in the onCreate method of the activity.

```
ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
ab.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.logo_actionbar); //this is your app logo or whatever youre using
ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

As long as the logo is cropped correctly it will be laid out as expected without having to worry about padding and offsets, although if you are using a drawer [there is a great sample on the android website](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) which shows how to set up a draw toggle properly